# Maximized window only on one Monitor when 2 Monitors in NVidia Surround activated

Tags: multiple-monitors, window, nvidia-settings

Maximize a window does not work correctly when using nvidia-surround.

I expect to maximize a window spanning ALL monitors in a nvidia-surround composition BUT its only maximized to ONE monitor!

### This is my nvidia-surround-setting:

[image]

### This is my system-settings:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: You have to ACTIVATE Nvidia surround :) It is usually a certain keyboard shortcut defined in the surround settings

Comment: @MaartenOlijve Surround is activated as you see in the screenshot.